# Phone Number Regex in Ruby -- Anchor error with ^$

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to validate user phone numbers in Ruby with the following format:

```
123-456-7890
(123) 456-7890
123 456 7890
123.456.7890
+91 (123) 456-7890
```

I used the following regex:

```
/^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/
```

And got this error when trying to create a user in the rails console:

**ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?**

I know there are gems for this but I would like to create the user model myself, making the phone number validation similar to the email:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/
  validates :phone_number, presence: true, length: {maximum: 15},
                    format: { with: VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

I've tried switching the anchors to \A and \z because that's what it seems to want me to do, but I cannot get the regex to accept the range of phone number inputs I want.  How can I fix the regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is at this line

```
VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/
```

it should be changed to

```
VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = /\A(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}\z/
```

Personally, I would suggest to avoid trying to use a single regex to validate all those formats. Either group similar formats, and use different regexps, or normalize the input and validate a few formats.

You may also want to [have a look at Phony](https://github.com/floere/phony).

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I will look into normalizing the input in future iterations.  I would like to eventually have the form have 3 separate input spaces for the phone number so I don't have to worry about - or . characters, just not sure how to do that in rails right now.